# Overlay image with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to overlay the content and the image on click in this image, but its only overlay my content.

Here the following code:

HTML :

```
<div class="picture-sell-item">
    <%= image_tag ('angel.png') %>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.picture-sell-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 250px 0;
    text-align: center;
    &.active {
        background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
        z-index: 10;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

JS :

```
$(".picture-sell-item img").on('click', function() {
    $(".picture-sell-item").addClass('active');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the background color of the wrapping div won't work as it sits below the image in the dom.

However if you use a pseudo `:before` element you can place this above the image as it's a separate object.

```js
$(".picture-sell-item img").on('click', function() {
  $(".picture-sell-item").addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.picture-sell-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.picture-sell-item.active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picture-sell-item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports">
</div>
```

Comment: all pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements require `content:` for them to be displayed.

Comment: You can find all you'll ever need to know about these elements here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html